# How to adb reboot in Genymotion using Mac?

Tags: genymotion

I have `Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip`
and `open_gapps-arm-7.0-stock-20180117.zip`

Drag and Drop, yes done. Then how to adb reboot in mac?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Genymotion adb, you can run `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb reboot`.

If you are using the Android SDK adb, then replace `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools` with the folder where Android SDK adb is installed.